# Omniscript inside a flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, omnistudio, dispatchevent

I'm trying to use an Omniscript inside a screen flow. To accomplish that I got the tag to embed the omni inside a LWC and finnaly be able to use it inside the flow. But I'm struggling with the communication between them, more specific how to get the output from the omni. I have tried the following  documentation, but it does not work: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_detect_data_json_updates_in_an_embedded_omniscript.htm&type=5
Basically in this doc I can use an event called omniaggregate to handle the JSON.

```
this.template.addEventListener('omniaggregate', this.omniUpdateHandler.bind(this));

omniUpdateHandler(event) { //do something with the data JSON here}
```

I was thinking of creating another lwc, but this time to place inside the omni, so I going to be able to dispatch a custom event and get it in the external lwc, but that just does not seem reasonable. Maybe I'm missing an easier way to accomplish that.

Someone could help me with that information, please? I there another/better way to use the omniscript data embedded in a flow?